# Getting parameters in sales_order_place_before event's observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am using `$request = $observer->getRequest();`in my observer method but it is not returning anything. i am using `sales_order_place_before`event.

Comment: $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
$params = $request->getParams();

Answer (score 5):

To get Request parameters in the Observer, use following code

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

To get post variable

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('your-param');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In starting, I was using checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method this event and, I was able to get request object by $request = $observer->getRequest(); and then I was accessing parameter by $request->getParam('parameter_name').
Can you tell me how to access this parameter by using sales_order_place_before  event.

Answer (score 1):

you can get shipping and billing array with below code

```
$shipping=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping');
$billing=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing');
$yourfieldname=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('yourfieldname');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My field name is delivery_day and I am printing Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('delivery_day')); but, it is not printing anything.

Comment: can you post the input field so i can check that?

Comment: <select name="delivery_day" id='emq_del_day'>
                <option value="">--Select Day--</option>
                <option value="Today">Today</option>
                <option value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
            </select>

Comment: I was using checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method this event and, I was able to get request object by $request = $observer->getRequest(); and then i was accessing parameter by $request->getParam('delivery_day').

Comment: use this event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` use in billing array  
`<select name="billing[delivery_day]" id='emq_del_day'> <option value="">--Select Day--</option> <option value="Today">Today</option> <option value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</option> </select>` and get it $billing['delivery_day'];

Comment: I want to check conditions before order getting placed. Can I use this event checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after?

Comment: no it is using after the order place use ``sales_order_place_before` as you mention in question

Comment: My simple requirement is , I want one event which will get fired when we click on Pace An Order button i.e before saving/placing an order and I can use         $request = $observer->getRequest();
 $quote = $observer->getQuote();
in  that event's observer method.

Comment: check the event what they return to observer https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Events+Reference

Comment: Thank you for that link. But, there is no other event where I can get $request and $quote.

Comment: sales_order_place_before use this event and use my answer and also field set in billing array you will get the result.

Comment: Actually problem is.. now I can not change that select field name, Bacause I have used that name in many places.. and problem is that checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method this event is firing every time when shipping method is changed.

Comment: Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams('delivery_day'); use this..

Comment: It return an array:
Array
(
    [payment] => Array
        (
            [method] => cashondelivery
        )

    [is_subscribed] => 1
    [customer_comment] => 
)

Comment: then you have to add in shipping['delivery_day'] array. or override the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to resolve your query:

```
public function yourFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent();
    echo $order->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethod(); // get selected paymante method

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    echo $quote->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); // get billing address phone number

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::place()`, the only available data for this event is `order`. To access the request object inside your event observer, you can do something like:

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In starting, I was using checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method this event and, I was able to get request object by $request = $observer->getRequest(); and then I was accessing parameter by $request->getParam('parameter_name').
Can you tell me how to access this parameter by using sales_order_place_before  event.

Comment: See my answer above: you don't have access to the request from the observer data, but you can still get the request object by calling `$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();` in your event observer.

Comment: That code is returing : Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http Object array but there are different  parameters present and parameters those I want are not present.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with below code to read all the parameters

```
 $orders = $observer->getData();
 echo '<pre>'; print_r($orders); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In starting, I was using checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method this event and, I was able to get request object by $request = $observer->getRequest(); and then I was accessing parameter by $request->getParam('parameter_name').
Can you tell me how to access this parameter by using sales_order_place_before  event.

Comment: You may use $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams(); to get the data

Answer (score 0):

```
public function yourFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent();
    echo $order->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethod(); // get selected paymante method

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    echo $quote->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(); // get billing address phone number
}
```